# Is there such a thing as a Fourier cipher, by another name?

Tags: php, encryption

I've created a type of alphabet cipher that is based on the concept of a Fourier transform, where each character is defined based on how distant it is (in the alphabet) from the preceding character:

```
function fourier_cipher($text) {

   $letters = array(1=>'a', 2=>'b', 3=>'c', 4=>'d', 5=>'e', 6=>'f', 7=>'g', 8=>'h', 9=>'i', 10=>'j', 11=>'k', 12=>'l', 13=>'m', 14=>'n', 15=>'o', 16=>'p', 17=>'q', 18=>'r', 19=>'s', 20=>'t', 21=>'u', 22=>'v', 23=>'w', 24=>'x', 25=>'y', 26=>'z');

   $chars = str_split($text);

   $prev_number = 0;
   $prev_difference = 0;

   for ($i=0; $i<count($chars); $i++) {
      $letter = $chars[$i];
      $number = array_search($letter,$letters);
      if ($number) {
         $difference = ($prev_difference > 13) ? 26 - abs($number - $prev_number) : abs($number - $prev_number);
         $code[$i] = $letters[$difference];
         $prev_number = $number;
         $prev_difference = $difference;
      }
      else {
         $code[$i] = $letter;
      }

   }

   return implode($code);

}
```

One of the benefits of this type of cipher is that, unlike a Caesar cipher, it can't be broken using normal letter-frequency analysis, since the cipher-letter that represents each actual letter is not constant throughout.

For example:

```
$text = 'we hold these truths to be self evident';
echo fourier_cipher($text);
// outputs: wh cgch pnwln kbcalk ae mc nlgf aqmeaif
```

I know very little about ciphers, so I'm assuming that this type of thing has been done before.

I'm curious: Does this type of cipher have a name -- and how easy is it to decipher, compared with other techniques?

Comment: There must be a shorter way to get your `letters` array.

Comment: Yeah, could probably use the str_split function on that, too.  But I was just lazy and grabbed what I had.

Comment: Yes, thank you -- I've corrected.

Comment: @SLaks  $letter = range('a','z');

Comment: @jpwco: `$letter = array_combine(range(1, 26), range('a', 'z'));`.

Comment: @Alix Axel +1 for attentive cleverness :)

Comment: This seems awfully similar to rot13 (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php).

Comment: @Alix: rot13 is a Caesar (shift) cipher; the function above is not.

Answer (score 1):

It is called 'Delta' cipher, or Delta encoding. See http://poj.org/problem?id=1453

It is a bit tedious to do manually. :) There doesn't seem to be an online decoder/encoder, although there was years ago.

Definitely not Vigenere, and it is easier to crack than Vigenere (if the vigenere keyword is not known).

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like Vigenere. At least to me. I'd try to break this with a Friedman Kappa test: find out the letter-gap frequencies related to how often they occure in the target-language. Still I don't see what this has to do with Fourier?

edit: see the comment

Comment: I don't think it could be classified as Vigenere, which does not (as far as I know) deal at all with the difference (in terms of number of characters in the alphabet) between letters.  I mentioned Fourier transforms because they, too, create representations based on the difference between adjacent values.

Comment: You're right. In that case still it is a polyalphabetic cipher. There're many of those, especially related to classic crypto. Very interesting approach indeed. I'll follow this thread and if no comes up with a perfect answer I'll ask my professor on Thursday morning ;)

Comment: Fourier transforms transform between spatial and frequency domains.  This is more of a differential encoding.  You're essentially calculating a discrete derivative of the string and encoding that with a simple substitution.  Not that your cipher isn't interesting, but I don't think it has anything to do with Fourier transforms.